# Scroll to bottom after componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Inside a div items are added dynamically. After the componentDidUpdate I want to scroll the content of a div, so that the last list-item gets visible.

css

```
div { 
   height: 100px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

react js

```
 return(
 <div>
  ...
  <div ref='wrap'>
   <ul>
     <li>item</li>
      ..
     <li>last item</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
    ...
</div>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the scrollTop property of the element to the current scrollHeight of the element. That would bring the scroll down to bottom.

You do not need to use jquery for this - `this.refs[refname]` gives you the DOM element on which you can act upon.

```
componentDidUpdate () {
  var el = this.refs.wrap;
  el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.